# MVC4 controller unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, moq

I'm using Ninject for IOC and separate repositories for each model.

I'm going to write some unit tests for controller, but **I don't want integration tests** - I already done that - **I don't want to touch DB**.

I have two choices

1. Use Moq, prepare all the setups and returns for moq objects
2. Use my already existing interfaces and Ninject to create my own in-memory repositories, which will not touch DB, but will return simple lists.

Which approach will be more correct from theoretical point of view?

For me, second option sounds better because it's going to test all the path: UnitTest -> Controller(myMockRepository) -> Controller.AddItem() -> myMockRepository.AddItem() and therefore test actual app architecture.

Or maybe these two options are just the same and I'm trying to overcomplicate simple things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injecting a mocked implementation into the controller usually provides more flexibility and control over the data that needs to be returned from the mock. In a unit test normally you shouldn't be using any dependency injection framework. A unit test is something that allows you to test the functionality of some method in complete **ISOLATION**.

Personally I would go with a mocking framework and then injected a mocked implementation of the repository into the controller.

This being said, depending on the implementation you are trying to mock, some people simply don't bother mocking their DAL. The DAL allows for substituting the actual database with an in-memory representation of the data. But without the need to write all the methods yourself for the test.